# Conditional execution of template defined inside 'steps' in Azure DevOps Yaml pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

This query is regarding Azure DevOps YAML pipeline. Is it possible to put an execution condition on any template defined inside 'steps'?

**For ex**:

1. Based on any pipeline variable value (dynamic, passed during pipeline run), decide whether to execute or not 'Task-1.yml'
2. Based on any variable value defined inside a shell script (using ##vso[task.setvariable variable=name]$value), decide whether to execute or not 'Task-3.yml'

Below is the Azure devops yaml pipeline structure:

```
stages:
- stage: Stage-A
  jobs:
  - job: Job-A
    steps:
      - template : Task-1.yml
      - template : Task-2.yml
      - template : Task-3.yml
```

I was able to do this at job level, however I cannot change pipeline structure to have more than 1 jobs since I need all tasks to execute on same build agent allocated at pipeline run.

I did lot of hit and trial to achieve this but somehow this is not working for me.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply a run-time condition for pipelines. The only way is to use template expression `${{ }}` but this is evaluated at a compile-time.

You can find these details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/template-expressions?view=azure-devops#context)

> Within a template expression, you have access to the parameters context that contains the values of parameters passed in. Additionally, you have access to the variables context that contains all the variables specified in the YAML file plus many of the predefined variables (noted on each variable in that article). Importantly, it doesn't have runtime variables such as those stored on the pipeline or given when you start a run. Template expansion happens early in the run, so those variables aren't available.

Comment: Hi, runtime conditions can be applied at job as well as step level. Refer to the below links. However, since I'm using templates within steps, that is where I'm not able to figure out how to apply conditions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages#use-the-output-variable-from-a-job-in-a-condition-in-a-subsequent-job

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages#use-the-pipeline-variable-created-from-a-step-in-a-condition-in-a-subsequent-step

Comment: They can be applied to jobs but not to templates. So you can apply them to each job in the template but not to the template istelf.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is passing the condition to the template like so:

```
stages:
- stage: Stage-A
  jobs:
  - job: Job-A
    steps:
      - template : Task-1.yml
        parameters:
          condition: ${{ yourConditionHere }} # such as "and(succeeded())"
      - template : Task-2.yml
      - template : Task-3.yml
```

And use it in the template like so:

```
parameters:
  - name:  condition
    type: string

steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: "Task name"
    inputs:
      targetType: "inline"
      script: |
        Write-Host "Hello world"
    condition: ${{ parameters.condition }}
```

Comment: It would be `parameters.condition`, not `variables.condition`